# Use pg_restore with AWS RDS Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, pg-restore

I'm trying to do a restore to a RDS Postgres Aurora database cluster. I have a backup of the database compressed into a `tar.gz` file. Upon extracting that file with the command `tar -xvf backup.tar.gz` it extracted several `dat.gz` files and also a `toc.dat` file. The database I am working with is quite large. I am now attempting to restore the database by tables in the backup. I am using `pg_restore`to restore the database. The version of `pg_restore` is version 14. Below is the command being used:

```
 pg_restore -v -x -t $table_name -U $db_user -h $RDS_Writer_Endpoint -p $db_port -d $db_name
```

After running this command, I seem to only get a hanging response. Some of the tables are not that large. Any insight on performing restores with these types of files would be helpful.

Comment: Don't extract the tar file, only unzip it. Then restore the tar file dump with `pg_restore`.

Comment: It's a tar.gz file. How do I unzip it without extracting it?

Comment: `gunzip filename`.